# Accessing SQL table function columns from SELECT stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a very large SELECT stored procedure that has multiple return columns and multiple INNER JOINS and LEFT JOINS. I also have a table function with 10 columns and the result set of the table function is based of a user ID.

My question is, how do I incorporate the table function into the main SELECT stored procedure and be able to return the columns from the table function based on the user ID.

MAIN STORED PROCEDURE:

```
SELECT     
      dbo.WebPersonalInfo.UserID, 
      dbo.WebPersonalInfo.FirstName, 
      dbo.WebPersonalInfo.MiddleInitial, 
      dbo.WebPersonalInfo.LastName,
      dbo.WebProgramParticipants.ParticipantID, 
      dbo.WebProgramParticipants.ProgramCode, 
FROM  dbo.WebProgramParticipants INNER JOIN
      dbo.WebPersonalInfo ON dbo.WebProgramParticipants.UserID = dbo.WebPersonalInfo.UserID 
WHERE     (dbo.WebProgramParticipants.ProgramCode = @programcode) 
ORDER BY dbo.WebPersonalInfo.LastName, dbo.WebPersonalInfo.FirstName
```

TABLE FUNCTION:

```
SELECT 
        ST1.SKILL_SET_ID AS SET1, SS1.SET_NAME AS NAME1, ST1.SKILL_SET_RATING AS R1,
        ST2.SKILL_SET_ID AS SET2, SS2.SET_NAME AS NAME2, ST2.SKILL_SET_RATING AS R2,
        ST3.SKILL_SET_ID AS SET3, SS3.SET_NAME AS NAME3, ST3.SKILL_SET_RATING AS R3,
        ST4.SKILL_SET_ID AS SET4, SS4.SET_NAME AS NAME4, ST4.SKILL_SET_RATING AS R4,
        ST5.SKILL_SET_ID AS SET5, ST5.SKILL_SET_OPTIONAL AS NAME5, ST5.SKILL_SET_RATING AS R5,
        ST6.SKILL_SET_ID AS SET6, ST6.SKILL_SET_OPTIONAL AS NAME6, ST6.SKILL_SET_RATING AS R6,
        ST7.SKILL_SET_ID AS SET7, ST7.SKILL_SET_OPTIONAL AS NAME7, ST7.SKILL_SET_RATING AS R7,
        CM.COMMENTS
    FROM IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_HDR HT
    LEFT JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_DTL ST1
        ON HT.ID = ST1.HDR_ID and st1.SKILL_SET_ID = 1
    INNER JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SETS SS1
        ON ST1.SKILL_SET_ID = SS1.ID
    LEFT JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_DTL ST2
        ON HT.ID = ST2.HDR_ID and st2.SKILL_SET_ID = 2
    INNER JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SETS SS2
        ON ST2.SKILL_SET_ID = SS2.ID
    LEFT JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_DTL ST3
        ON HT.ID = ST3.HDR_ID and st3.SKILL_SET_ID = 3
    INNER JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SETS SS3
        ON ST3.SKILL_SET_ID = SS3.ID
    LEFT JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_DTL ST4
        ON HT.ID = ST4.HDR_ID and st4.SKILL_SET_ID = 4
    INNER JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SETS SS4
        ON ST4.SKILL_SET_ID = SS4.ID
    LEFT JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_DTL ST5
        ON HT.ID = ST5.HDR_ID and st5.SKILL_SET_ID = 5
    INNER JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SETS SS5
        ON ST5.SKILL_SET_ID = SS5.ID
    LEFT JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_DTL ST6
        ON HT.ID = ST6.HDR_ID and st6.SKILL_SET_ID = 10
    INNER JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SETS SS6
        ON ST6.SKILL_SET_ID = SS6.ID
    LEFT JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_DTL ST7
        ON HT.ID = ST7.HDR_ID and st7.SKILL_SET_ID = 11
    INNER JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SETS SS7
        ON ST7.SKILL_SET_ID = SS7.ID
    INNER JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_COMMENTS CM
        ON HT.ID = CM.HDR_ID
    WHERE HT.PARTICIPANT_ID = @PARTICIPANT_ID
    GROUP BY PARTICIPANT_ID, ST1.SKILL_SET_ID, SS1.SET_NAME, ST1.SKILL_SET_RATING, ST2.SKILL_SET_ID, SS2.SET_NAME, ST2.SKILL_SET_RATING, ST3.SKILL_SET_ID, SS3.SET_NAME, ST3.SKILL_SET_RATING, ST4.SKILL_SET_ID, SS4.SET_NAME, ST4.SKILL_SET_RATING, ST5.SKILL_SET_ID, ST5.SKILL_SET_OPTIONAL, ST5.SKILL_SET_RATING, ST6.SKILL_SET_ID, ST6.SKILL_SET_OPTIONAL, ST6.SKILL_SET_RATING, ST7.SKILL_SET_ID, ST7.SKILL_SET_OPTIONAL, ST7.SKILL_SET_RATING, CM.COMMENTS
```

Comment: Sample code would help us to be able to help you.

Comment: I would show the code for the main stored procedure but it is hideously huge.

Comment: By the way, the left joins in your function are pointless the way they are written. Try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andomar's answer is correct, but... have you considered just using a VIEW instead? Much simpler, and almost certainly faster.

Take the function, remove the WHERE clause, and add PARTICIPANT_ID to the SELECT list; that's your view. You then JOIN to it just as if it were a table, on Participant_ID.

Comment: Ok if I took the exact code out of the table function, how would I reference the columns from the main stored procedure

Comment: Oh wait, this would not be good for memory purposes.This will be called approx. 230 times when ran

Comment: Take the function, remove the WHERE clause, and add PARTICIPANT_ID to the SELECT list; that's your view. You then JOIN to it just as if it were a table, on Participant_ID. Let me know if you need more, I'll do it in a separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `outer apply` or `inner apply` to use a function table like a regular one:

```
select  *
from    users u
outer apply
        dbo.fn_YourFunction(u.id) yf
```

This would return all columns from the function.

Comment: I added a stripped down version of the stored procedure and teh table function

Comment: @mattgcon: So, add `outer apply dbo.YourFunction(WebPersonalInfo.UserID)` to the query?

Comment: I tried to add this after all of the joins but I am getting an "Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'outer'" and all I am doing is adding right after the last inner join

Comment: Is your database in 2000 compatibility mode?  (Visible in properties of the database)

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? (Never mind -- missed the 2005 tag)

Comment: I do not know, I cannot access the properties and I have full access rights to the db

Comment: @mattgcon: Ask your sysadmin/dba?

Comment: Thats me, well Im in charge of the DB at least, but the username I am logged in as has full privileges, in fact I am the owner of the db

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are asking, but reading a little into this...

You can join to a table-valued function:

```
SELECT *
FROM existing tables and joins
LEFT JOIN tvf(@userid /* param to SP */)
    ON whatever
```

You can also apply the table-valued function to the row:

```
SELECT *
FROM existing tables and joins
OUTER APPLY tvf(userid /* column from above joins */)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retreive data from a sql function using `SELECT * FROM yourfunction()`. So perhaps you can use some `JOINS` on `UserID` to your main SELECT along with yourfuncition() as shown above.

You will need to be more specific to get a better answer.